# PayUMoney integration in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.ios, payment-gateway, payumoney

I'm implementing PayUMoney in Xamarin Forms. PayUMoney don't have any official SDKs for Xamarin so handling it natively using Hybrid Webview.

In Android it's working fine like I'm able to get Javascript callbacks on Success and Failure of the payment but in iOS, I'm not getting callbacks.

I don't know how should we write Javascript for this webview and evaluate it. I'm unable to find it after exploring.

It would be very helpful if anyone helps in this. Thanks

Comment: If you show the code you have done it will be a bit easier for anyone to help you. Please update the original post with the code used for the iOS WebView.